# How can I restrict search field to return only services and orders belonging to the same user logged in?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a search route and wish to restrict results to only return services and orders belonging the company logged in
Another issue is the return results for the orders is empty although there are orders registered on my database

So far I've managed to get the id from token and make an if condition but it doesn't seem to work

````
export const handlingSearchForCompany = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  const searchQuery = req.query.search;
  const regexSearch = new RegExp(searchQuery, 'i');
  const token = req.headers['token'];
  const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.TOKEN_KEY);
  const companyId = decoded.id;
  if (companyId == req.currentUser.id) {
    const services = await Service.find({ title: regexSearch }).select({
      title: 1,
    });
    //   Search orders by user
      const orders = await OrderModel.find({ 'user.full_name': regexSearch }).select({
        'user.full_name': 1,
      });

    res.json({
      status: 'success',
      data: {
          orders,
        services,
      },
    });
  } else {
    return next(new ErrorAPI('No service available'));
    // Search services by title
  }
});```
````

Comment: 1. Please post your services schema and your orders schema. 2. Can you make sure that `console.log(req.query.search)` has an actual value in there? 3. Does `services` contain matching documents or an empty array?